Invalid conversion from runtime DealFlowController to System.Callable
I am writing a remote action for my omniscript. In the Remote action, I've mentioned my classname and my method name correctly. I am not passing any remote options or extra payload. Here is my class code:
global with sharing class DealFlowController implements vlocity_cmt.VlocityOpenInterface
{

global DealFlowController(){}

global Boolean invokeMethod(String methodName, Map<String,Object> inputMap, Map<String,Object> outMap, Map<String,Object> options) {
    Boolean result = true;
    try{
        if(methodName.equals('createOpportunity')){
            createOpportunity(inputMap);                                                                 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){   
        result = false;
    }
    return result;   
}

public void createOpportunity(Map<String,Object> inputMap){
    system.debug('Got the data in createOportunity' + JSON.serialize(inputMap));
}
}

What could be the reason for this?

The OmniScript is expecting a Callable but you're using vlocity_cmt.VlocityOpenInterface, which is used for different operations. Use Callable to implement your method:
global with sharing class DealFlowController implements Callable {
  // ...
  global Object call(String methodName, Map<String, Object> params) {


Thanks for answering. But, why does then the documentation says to implement the NS. VlocityOpenInterface instead of Callable?
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_example_13669.htm&type=5
Also, I could not find any documentation that clearly gives guideline for implementing an Apex class as remote action from omniscript apart from above. Also, in case of using Callable, what parameter from omniscript maps to 2nd parameter of call method?

@Sarang See Callable Implementations. The second parameter will have three keys, input, output, and options. My memory's a bit fuzzy on OS, but if I recall correctly, which interface you use is configured in the Integration Procedure. You can either change to the callable interface in code, or you can change the IP settings to use the newer interface.

My error has changed to something else. Thanks for clarification @sfdcfox, I will continue to debug that and see if it's because of my code logic or anything else.

@Sarang Feel free to ask a new question if you still have trouble. We'll be happy to help.

As per your previous comment, "which interface you use is configured in the Integration Procedure". But in my case I am calling the apex from omniscript without any IP involved. How and where do I change the settings in this case?

To anyone else that runs across this, the docs mention that you have to replace "NS" with the namespace of your omnistudio package installation. You can find information on how to get the namespace here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_remote_action_13618.htm&type=5
Then use this template (remember to replace NS in the implements portion) to adjust your class. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_example_13669.htm&type=5#:~:text=Sample%20Class%20Structure
